# How to load specific PostGIS features from a given table into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have a table in my database built like this:

```
contour_id / (INT) project_id / (INT) contour_lvl / (INT) contour_geom (MultiLineString Geom)
```

Each row in this table is a contour feature associated with a project.

How can I load into QGIS a specific set of features from this table (ex: using only `project_id = 10` ?

It looks like I can only import the whole table, which is not useful for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the window where you select your table from your postgisdatabase, you have to doubleclick the layer

[image]

Then a query-window opens where you can define what features you want to load from your table

[image]